# Toggle divs and animate an arrow if the section's checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, toggle, show-hide

So I have a bunch of divs like this:

```
<div class="section-head" id="contact-info">
        <i class="fa fa-3x fa-user"></i>
    <div class="section-info">
        <h4>Contact Information</h4>
        <p>The bare minimum you need to get started</p>
    </div>
      <div class="onoffswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
       <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch"></label>
    </div>
          <div class="arrow-down"></div>
  </div>
<div class="contact-info">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at massa luctus, suscipit ligula ut, tristique purus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Maecenas tincidunt pulvinar libero, eget iaculis libero placerat at. Fusce vitae nisl volutpat, laoreet tellus ac, lobortis orci. Proin felis ipsum, imperdiet nec aliquam in, venenatis sed magna. In mollis tempus maximus. Pellentesque eget nisl tempor lorem condimentum vestibulum. Quisque ante odio, eleifend id facilisis sed, tincidunt sed nunc. Ut porttitor commodo nulla, sagittis feugiat ante. Aenean pellentesque ante at interdum dignissim. Fusce et est ac est scelerisque porta vel at justo. Maecenas non lectus purus. Cras congue egestas rutrum. Praesent lobortis mattis ante, eget dictum lorem maximus sed. Vestibulum sed ipsum eget magna pellentesque volutpat. Morbi ultrices massa ante, in congue nisl lobortis semper.

    Praesent eleifend nisl est, ac pulvinar erat venenatis volutpat. Sed tempus rutrum sapien, vel sagittis massa sagittis ac. Nullam aliquet enim non accumsan imperdiet. Integer enim turpis, eleifend eget sollicitudin ac, ornare nec purus. Etiam non ex orci. Mauris fringilla, diam nec viverra posuere, nisl nulla malesuada mauris, eu placerat lacus turpis ullamcorper arcu. Nullam placerat facilisis urna eu consequat. Sed luctus tellus in nisi vestibulum consectetur. Etiam tincidunt pellentesque laoreet. 
</div>

<div class="section-head" id="merchant-services">
        <i class="fa fa-3x fa-credit-card"></i>
    <div class="section-info">
        <h4>Merchant Services</h4>
        <p>The bare minimum you need to get started</p>
    </div>
      <div class="onoffswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch2">
       <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch2"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow-down"></div>
</div>
<div class="merchant-services">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at massa luctus, suscipit ligula ut, tristique purus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Maecenas tincidunt pulvinar libero, eget iaculis libero placerat at. Fusce vitae nisl volutpat, laoreet tellus ac, lobortis orci. Proin felis ipsum, imperdiet nec aliquam in, venenatis sed magna. In mollis tempus maximus. Pellentesque eget nisl tempor lorem condimentum vestibulum. Quisque ante odio, eleifend id facilisis sed, tincidunt sed nunc. Ut porttitor commodo nulla, sagittis feugiat ante. Aenean pellentesque ante at interdum dignissim. Fusce et est ac est scelerisque porta vel at justo. Maecenas non lectus purus. Cras congue egestas rutrum. Praesent lobortis mattis ante, eget dictum lorem maximus sed. Vestibulum sed ipsum eget magna pellentesque volutpat. Morbi ultrices massa ante, in congue nisl lobortis semper.

        Praesent eleifend nisl est, ac pulvinar erat venenatis volutpat. Sed tempus rutrum sapien, vel sagittis massa sagittis ac. Nullam aliquet enim non accumsan imperdiet. Integer enim turpis, eleifend eget sollicitudin ac, ornare nec purus. Etiam non ex orci. Mauris fringilla, diam nec viverra posuere, nisl nulla malesuada mauris, eu placerat lacus turpis ullamcorper arcu. Nullam placerat facilisis urna eu consequat. Sed luctus tellus in nisi vestibulum consectetur. Etiam tincidunt pellentesque laoreet. 
  </div>
```

The arrow needs to transition down and the div with text should appear when the box is checked. I have found a lot of examples of how to do this with one checkbox and one div, but I need to find a efficient way to do this with all of my divs/ checkboxes without writing jquery for each individual checkbox. Any advice would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm right to understand your question.

this piece of jQuery source code may be helpful.

```
function dispToggle(getThis) {
    var isChecked   = getThis.is(":checked");
    var targetElem  = getThis.parent().parent().next();
    if(isChecked) {
        $(targetElem).show();
    }
    else {
        $(targetElem).hide();
    }
}
$(".section-head").find("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
    dispToggle($(this));
});
$(".section-head").find("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    dispToggle($(this));
});
```